# Size of tab in sencha

Tags: css, tabs, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to modify the size of the tab in css.
I found the variable $tabs-bottom-icon-size which modify only the size of the icons in the tab.
Is there any variable which allows me to modify the size of the entire tab?
And if not,how can i do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You will have to just override the height of both the `.x-tabbar` and `.x-tab` classes.

```
.x-tabbar {
    height: 5em;
}
.x-tab {
    height: 4.5em;
}
```

Comment: But how can i change the icon size??