# How to make bigger icons in bottom tab bar in sencha?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, tabbar

In my application, i added a bottom tab bar with home icon and feedback icon using iconCls. But as i am developing for android tablet, it is coming very small. How can i make those icon big? and how to align properly?? means one icon in left, another in middle and another in right..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: nops..but that for alignment..but how to get bigger icons??

Comment: Dont forget to accept an answer if any of them helped you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way i am able to increase the icon size:

```
.x-tabbar.x-docked-bottom .x-tab .x-button-icon { -webkit-mask-size: 2.5em; width: 2.5em; height: 2.5em; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; background-color:#D7E4BD; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the 1.65em value into something bigger. But keep the same value everywhere.

```
.x-tabbar .x-tab .x-button-icon {
  -webkit-mask-size: 1.65em;
  width: 1.65em;
  height: 1.65em;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried with this. But still it is not coming                        .x-tabbar > * {
  z-index: 4;
}
.x-tabbar .x-tab .x-button-icon {
  -webkit-mask-size: 12em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
}

Comment: Using below code i am able to make bigger the icons..but label of the icons is still very small and i want some space between the icons also.. here is my code                                                      .x-tabbar.x-docked-bottom .x-tab .x-button-icon {
 -webkit-mask-size: 2.5em;
 width: 2.5em;
 height: 2.5em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 background-color:#D7E4BD;
}

Answer (score 1):

For alignment, use `iconAlign`

For size adjustment, see [Size of tab in sencha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210114/size-of-tab-in-sencha)

Comment: .x-tabbar{
tabs-bottom-icon-size: 5em;
}                                                                      I tried in this way..but no result

Comment: the point is you have to make sure that you are changing the CSS properties which **actually affect** the tab size, and then define a custom one, set it `!important`.